# Place text on the radii extending from the center of a circle D3

Tags: javascript, text, d3.js, rotation, geometry

I've got (using D3) a circular arc that I have a number of evenly spaced points on. I need to place some text on the radius extending through the center of the circle, through the center of the point on the arc.

So to visualize, the text at unit circle position zero would be not be rotated. The text at unit circle position 90 degrees would be rotated 90 degrees. The text at -90 degrees would be rotated 90... etc.

I have tried doing something like this.

```
var labelTextUpdate = this.svg
    .select('#nodes')
    .selectAll('text')
    .data(circleData, function(d) { return d.id;});

var labelTextEnter = labelTextUpdate.enter()
    .append('text')
    .style('text-anchor', 'start')
    .attr('x', function(d) { return d.coords.x;})
    .attr('y', function(d) { return d.coords.y;})
    .attr('transform', function(d) {
        return 'rotate(' + d.angle + ')';
    })
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.type;
    });

labelTextUpdate
    .transition().duration(400)
    .attr('x', function(d) { return d.coords.x;})
    .attr('y', function(d) { return d.coords.y;})
    .attr('transform', function(d) {
        return 'rotate(' + d.angle + ')';
    });
```

I'll admit, I don't know the most about D3, but the code as I have it right now, minus the "transform" lines, sticks the text right on top of the point on the arc where I want it, so I must be close.

However, it doesn't look as though I am able to pass in an angle to the transform attribute? When I try the code that I have pasted, the text goes away. When I forget about trying to parametrize the angle and just use a constant angle

```
.attr('transform', 'rotate(5)');
```

This appears to achieve the desired rotation of my text, but I don't want all of the text to be rotated the same angle.

Would anyone know how to fix my almost working code?

Comment: Have you seen [this example](https://www.jasondavies.com/coffee-wheel/)?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't end up figuring out what I needed from your link, but that is exactly how I wanted my text to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. I was on the right track with the rotate function, but you need to also supply a point around which to rotate.

Something like this

```
.attr('transform', function(d) {
    return "rotate(" + angle + ", " + x + ", " + y + ")";
});
```

I'm guessing that without the provided rotation point (x,y), D3 must to default to whatever it thinks is the best guess. That best guess took my text right out of my svg area. I don't know if this will end up helping anyone, but it answered my question and it took me a while to find out about the additional parameters that rotate can take.